# Deserializing JSON to non-static nested classes using Gson

Tags: java, json, parsing, gson

According to [this](http://programmerbruce.blogspot.com/2011/06/gson-v-jackson.html#TOC-Nested-Classes-including-Inner-Clas) Gson can deserialize to inner classes. I have the next fragment of JSON string:

```
...
"coordinates": {
    "coordinates": [106.80552006,-6.22016938],
    "type": "Point",
}
...
```

I'm using the next class:

```
public class Tweet {
  public Coordinates coordinates = new Coordinates();

  public class Coordinates {
    public double[] coordinates;
  }
}
```

and trying to parse the my JSON string:

```
Tweet tweet = gson.fromJson(string, Tweet.class);
Tweet.Coordinates tweetCoordinates = gson.fromJson(string, Tweet.Coordinates.class);
```

But I get this error:

```
Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT
```

Could you please tell me where the mistake is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I used Gson with nested classes I always needed to make them `static` to work... In your link they say that it's not necessary, but in [**Gson documentation**](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Nested-Classes-including-Inner-Classes-) it's clearly said:

> "Gson can also deserialize static nested classes. However, Gson can not
>   automatically deserialize the pure inner classes since their no-args
>   constructor also need a reference to the containing Object which is
>   not available at the time of deserialization. You can address this
>   problem by either making the inner class static or by providing a
>   custom InstanceCreator for it."

---

Anyway, if it's actually possible deserialize to a non-static inner class, your problem would be that...

First you are parsing the JSON with your class `Tweet` with:

```
Tweet tweet = gson.fromJson(string, Tweet.class);
```

which should be working, since the class `Tweet` *matches* the JSON response. However, then you are trying to parse the same JSON response with the class `Coordinates`, which obviously doesn't *match* the JSON response... moreover it makes no sense at all to parse the same response twice!

If your first parsing is actually working, if you then want to access the `Coordinates` object, just do:

```
Tweet.Coordinates tweetCoordinates = tweet.getCordinates();
```

If the parsing with the class `Tweet` is not working either, try to make the inner class `static`, and if that doesn't work either, please comment and I'll try to find another solution...

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now everything works fine even with non-static inner class.