# GSON deserialization: nested JSon file error

Tags: java, json, gson

I am trying to parse JSon File and I cannot figure my mistake (smaller examples work flawlessly)

Song.json

```
{
    "song": {
        "fileInfo": {
            "version": "0.1",
            "createdIn": "PickWorks Studio",
            "modifiedIn": "PickWorks Studio",
            "modified": "2010-01-28T13:15:30+01:00"
        },
        "properties": {
            "authors": [
                {
                    "name": "Juri Traktori",
                    "type": "music",
                    "lang": "en"
                }
            ],
            "titles": [
                {
                    "title": "Rainy day",
                    "lang": "en",
                    "original": true
                },
                {
                    "title": "Descowe dni",
                    "lang": "pl"
                }
            ],
            "copywright": "Michal Tomanek",
            "released": "19-03-1993",
            "transposition": -3,
            "tempo": {
                "type": "text/bpm",
                "value": "moderate/90"
            },
            "key": "A",
            "version": 0.99,
            "publisher": "myself",
            "keywords": [ "grace", "words","amazing"],
            "verseOrder": "v1 v2 v1 v1 v2",
            "themes": [
                {
                    "theme": "adoration"
                }
            ]
        },
        "lyrics": [
            {
                "section": "v1",
                "lines": [
                    {
                        "lang": "en",
                        "part": "man",
                        "text": "How <chord name=\"A\"/>great is <br/>your love",
                        "comment": "Sing softly"
                    },
                    {
                        "lang": "en",
                        "part": "woman",
                        "text": "How great is your love to us"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

SongType.java: (is rather long) http://pastebin.com/uaEY7dty

When I do as usualy:

```
Gson gson = new Gson() ;
SongType parsed = gson.fromJson(json, SongType.class);
```

It crashes... I am stuck on it for several days and cannot get it right.

BTW: it is my first question on SO, so please excuse me if it is not presented as it should be.

EDIT:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 692
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:176)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:93)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:172)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:93)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:172)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:803)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:768)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:717)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:689)
    at Main.main(Main.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 692
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginObject(JsonReader.java:374)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:165)
```

**EDIT 2:**

1) Song is now static
2) Lyrics are inside List (there are more sections inside)

**EDIT 3:**

```
import java.util.List;

public class SongType {
    public static Song song;

    public class Song {
        public FileInfo     fileInfo;
        public Properties   properties;
        public List<Lyrics> lyrics;

        public FileInfo getFileInfo()     {return fileInfo;}
        public Properties getProperties() {return properties;}
        public List<Lyrics> getLyrics()   {return lyrics;}

        public void setFileInfo(FileInfo fileInfo)       {this.fileInfo   = fileInfo;}
        public void setProperties(Properties properties) {this.properties = properties;}
        public void setLyrics(List<Lyrics> lyrics)       {this.lyrics     = lyrics;}
    } 
//code continues here ...
```

But it still doesn't work ... Am I missing something else ?

Comment: Can you put the error message in the post. Otherwise it is very difficult to know what to look for.

Comment: Please add the exception's stack trace and how exactly it crashes. You can do that with the `edit` link under your question.

Comment: What field of the class is it not able to deserialize?

Comment: I don't know exactly where it crashes... (I gave strong C/C++ background and only 2 weeks of Java - still have problems with debugs)

Comment: About edit3, have you another exception? If yes, post it. Another info required, are you parsing the same JSON as question or another one?

Comment: @giampalo thats the full file: http://pastebin.com/4EbHUGjf, error is the same

Comment: while I'm checking your file again, to be sure, did you do a clean of compiled classes of your project?

Comment: @giampaolo ... yeah... I did clean build

Comment: @giampaolo 
SongType : http://pastebin.com/yYMdzSV0

Comment: I can confirm you that I can correctly parse it. Is SongType class defined in its own file? How do you get your JSON? Did you try to put it into a string variable and parse it from there?

Comment: My working project (you can import it in Eclipse, if you use it) https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1FU8N8yxXPpTmNhdUtGdVBTNVk/edit?usp=sharing&pli=1

Comment: Restarted computer created new project and imported classes again and it is working. Thank you all for your help!

P.S.: let's blame the part after the List<Lyrics> on windows ... as usual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem with `Lyrics` field, Gson expects an object but you provide an array (with an object only).

This is your your class:

```
 public class Song {
                public FileInfo   fileInfo;
                public Properties properties;
                public Lyrics    lyrics;
                // more rows
```

and this is your unmatched part of JSON

```
 "lyrics": [
      //more things here      
  ]
```

As you can see, with square bracket, a new array begins.

To solve, change `lyrics` field to `List<Lyrics>` if you want to parse it as is, otherwise change your JSON, if you can, removing square brackets. Of course you have to change also getter and setter for `lyric` field. In code terms, change like this:

```
 public static class Song {
      public FileInfo   fileInfo;
      public Properties properties;
      public List<Lyrics>    lyrics;

      public FileInfo getFileInfo()     {return fileInfo;}
      public Properties getProperties() {return properties;}
      public List<Lyrics> getLyrics()                 {return lyrics;}

      public void setFileInfo(FileInfo fileInfo)               {this.fileInfo   = fileInfo;}
      public void setProperties(Properties properties) {this.properties = properties;}
      public void setLyrics(List<Lyrics> lyrics)                     {this.lyrics     = lyrics;}
 }
```

This is my execution:

```
    Gson gson = new Gson() ;
    SongType parsed = gson.fromJson(s, SongType.class);
    System.out.print(parsed.song.getLyrics().get(0).getLines().get(0).getText());
```

with this result:

```
How <chord name="A"/>great is <br/>your love
```

Comment: in original file there is more then one object inside Lyrics ...
changed it to List<Lyrics> but error is still the same ...

Comment: In the sample you provided, there an array with only one lyric inside. Anycase, use a list of lyrics

Comment: @user1741772: if you use a List<Lyrics> and set their getter and setter accordingly it will work. I tested it locally, both with `GSON` and with the `Jackson` mapper (which is a library that does the same thing)

Comment: Thanks @RaulRene for your confirmation

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues here.

1. Lyrics is an array in the JSON file, but your variable is not. Change it to `List<Lyrics>`
2. The inner class `Song` is not static, which can be an issue (although apparently this is working for you): [see here why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16576027/1300817).