# How to deserialize non-static inner classes with Gson?

Tags: java, gson, nested-class

It is said in Gson manual, that it is possible to deserialize non-static inner classes if custom instance creator written: https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Nested-Classes-including-Inner-Classes-

I don't understand, how to accomplish that? I need to register instance creator to use it, but to register it, I need an instance of it. Hence, I can't put enclosing class into cosntructor.

How to?

Comment: maybe this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574998/deserializing-json-to-non-static-nested-classes-using-gson

Comment: 'Non-static inner' is a tautology.

Comment: Do you have a code sample that you need to serialize/deserialize that contains an inner class?