# Is there a way to modify enclosing class reference?

Tags: java, reflection, nested, gson

I have enclosing and nested classes like this:

```
public class Promotion {
    protected int id;
    protected List<Image> images;
    //...

    public class Image {
        private String id;
        private String aspect_ration;

        public Promotion getPromotion() {
            return Promotion.this;    //<-- Always null.
        }
    }
}
```

The objects of this class are being automatically created and initialized by Gson from json strings.

For some reason (instantiating by `Gson`), in the nested class instances, the `Promotion.this` is `null`. Setting it manually is impossible, because the statement `Promotion.this = promotion;` causes compile error: `Variable expected`.

So is there any way to do something like this: (either by normal Java way, or some Java Reflection trick)

```
public class Promotion {
    //...

    public class Image {

        public void setPromotion(Promotion promotion) {
            Promotion.this = promotion;   //<-- Is not possible.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot. Don't serialise nested classes.

Comment: You'd need to call the correct constructor and to do that you might need a custom deserializer (I'm not a GSON expert though).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deserializing JSON to non-static nested classes using Gson](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574998/deserializing-json-to-non-static-nested-classes-using-gson)

Comment: Guys the `Gson` part is just for explanation. My question is a basic java syntax question. I hoped to learn some java syntax or some kind of "Reflection magic" to make it possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way myself by using `Reflection`. The method in question can be implemented like this:

```
public void setPromotion(Promotion promotion) throws IllegalAccessException
{
    try {
        Field enclosingThisField = Image.class.getDeclaredField("this$0");
        enclosingThisField.setAccessible(true);
        enclosingThisField.set(this, promotion);
    }
    catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {}
}
```

**Edit:** This is working in my environment (*Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_92-b14)*), but I'm not sure if it's guaranteed to work on every JVM.

Comment: The original error being that the gson deserialisation did not consider nested classes. +1 for the nice perversion of the month. ;)

Comment: @JoopEggen Thank you :)

Comment: This is truly painful. I hope never to encounter this in production code...

Comment: @BoristheSpider I know, but it's just a workaround to overcome the shortcoming of gson. And I think it's cost is less than being forced to write custom gson deserializers.

Comment: It certainly costs more than simply adding `static` to the class definition. And are you certain that the name `this$0` is defined in the Java spec? I would suggest either making the inner class `static` or adding an `InstanceCreator`.

Comment: No actually I'm not sure. In some of my use cases it's semantically not good to add `static`, because one way or another, I need to associate objects of nested class to enclosing class.

Comment: But I see the point. Maybe it's just better to add a simple manual reference to enclosing class, instead of trying to fix `Enclosing.this`.